# Mysql query to get the distinct count by current year and last year on the same date

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am trying to get the distinct count of (ordno,partno) by the date for current year and last year..Please find below the DDL for the input and the output tables.

```
Create table input
(ordno varchar(20),
partno varchar(40),
orddate date)

insert into input values
('BC132','13211','4/1/2022'),
('NM121','8901','4/1/2022'),
('JK121','90122','4/1/2022'),
('NM121','9021','4/1/2021'),
('KL123','634','4/1/2021'),
('OP121','453','4/1/2021'),
('KL121','6781','4/1/2021'),
('KL1234','93211','4/15/2022'),
('OQ121','431','4/15/2022'),
('HJ121','321','4/15/2022'),
('M213','221','4/15/2022'),
('B121','901','4/15/2022')


Create table output
(orddate date,
currentyear int,
last year int)

insert into output values
('Apr 01',3','4'),
('Apr 15',3','2')
```

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: You have provided input and expected output, but there is missing your attempt at the problem. SO is not intended as a complete solution providing site, but one that helps you correct errors in your own solutions.

Comment: @Gnudiff: Sorry I forgot to post my try ...I will update the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result and  create table statement and data examples doesn't match each other.

I used proper date datatype and used [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to give your expected format.

Try:

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(orddate,'%b %d') as my_date,
       count(case when YEAR(orddate)='2022' then partno  end) as currentyear,
       count(case when YEAR(orddate)='2021' then partno  end) as last_year  
from input
group by my_date;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ef1f4ccf86a8089834a589db6fe4ffa